# Automatically add new row to table when editing last one

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to add a new row to the end of the table when user starts typing in last row.
The viewmodel looks like this one:

```
function tableRow(number, ownerViewModel) {  
    this.number = ko.observable(number);
    this.remove = function () { ownerViewModel.tableRows.destroy(this); }

    ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var curval = this.number();
        var rows = ownerViewModel.tableRows();
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            if (curval != '' && this == rows[rows.length - 1]) {
                ownerViewModel.addNewRow();
            }
        }
    }, this);
}

function tableRowsViewModel() {
    var that = this;
    this.tableRows = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.addNewRow = function () {
        this.tableRows.push(new tableRow('', that));
    }
    this.addNewRow();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new tableRowsViewModel());
});
```

And here is html:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Number
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template:{name:'tableRow', foreach: tableRows}">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <button type="button" data-bind="click: addNewRow">
                    add row
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script id="tableRow" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:40px;" data-bind="value: number, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" data-bind="click: function(){ $data.remove(); }">
                delete
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I've also inserted `alert()` in tableRow ko.dependentObservable function:

```
ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    alert('test');
    var curval = this.number();...
```

It seems like this function is fired 5 times when tableRows array contain 2 elements, 6 times when there are 3 elements in array and so on.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependentObservable that you are adding to each row object is firing each time that a row is added, because they depend on `tableRows`.  So, each one is doing some work to determine if they are the last row.  If it is the last row, then a new row is added.

An alternative is to use a single dependentObservable that represents the last row's value.  Then, you can subscribe to changes to that dependentObservable, check if it has a value, and add a row when necessary.  It would look something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/F5F8S/

Also, here is a sample that I had from the KO forums that shows adding a row and also removing the last row if the last two are empty in case it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MzGDr/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle link.  Any idea why http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/F5F8S/  works with knockout-2.0.0 but not with the latest knockout-2.1.0 ?

Comment: There was a change in 2.1 that doesn't allow a computed observable to cause itself to re-evaluate including subscriptions to itself.  The easiest solution is to do the row add in a setTimeout so that it is not in the same execution context like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/F5F8S/17/